# Conceptual question about the extended real line and being a vector space.

Tags: vector-spaces

Last time I was chatting with a professor online on a public IRC, this is a transcript:

> #Professor (16:20:12): So what was your question?
>
> #Me (16:20:22): I feel stupid....
>
> #Professor (16:20:40): I will do my best so that you feel smarter, just ask away!
>
> #Me (16:22:39): Consider the extended real  line with its particular operations, I made a reasoning that it wasn't a vector space over **R** that said: since (-∞)+(-∞)=-∞, and since +∞ is the additive inverse of -∞, we can add to both sides +∞ to get -∞=0, but one of the properties of a vector space is the uniqueness of the additive identity, but here it isn't unique hence it isn't  a vector space. Is this correct?
>
> *User:'Professor' has quitted the chat. (16:22:43)*

So I still don't know whether my reasoning is correct, do you?

Comment: Typical professor...

Comment: Best prof ever ...!!!

Comment: Thanks for the chuckle. "Quitted?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that $\infty+(-\infty)$ is usually not defined, so the addition structure is not quite nice enough to be a vector space.

Comment: I have as axioms: (+∞)+(-∞)=0, (+∞)+(+∞)=+∞, (-∞)+(-∞)=(-∞).

Comment: What about $0\cdot\infty$? That's also usually not defined.

Comment: It is defined in my text as 0.

Comment: Okay. Then I would say your reasoning about uniqueness is correct.

Comment: If you assume that the extended real line with the operations you gave is a vector space, then your reasoning correctly gives a contradiction.  As par said, the conventions in your textbook are not exactly standard.

Comment: But is there an axiom that says that for each u,v,w, in our vector space if u=v then u+w=v+w ? Or we can derive it from the regular axioms of a vector space (Commutativity, Associativity, Existence of an additive identity, Existence of additive inverses, Existence of a Multiplicative identity and finally the distributive property)?

Comment: Can such definitions be consistent? For example, $(+\infty+(-\infty))+a=0+a=a=+\infty+(-\infty+a)=+\infty+(-\infty)=0$?

Comment: That's what I was saying @Kyson, but is what I said in the previous comment justified?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. In particular, it is a standard theorem that the additive identity is a unique element of a vector space. Further, neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$ are elements of $\mathbf R$. By your book's definition, $+\infty + (-\infty) = 0$, so $-\infty = -\infty + (-\infty) \implies +\infty + (-\infty) = +\infty + (-\infty) + (-\infty)$, and we derive the statement $0 = -\infty$. This of course implies that $-\infty$ is itself an additive identity, but $-\infty$ is not a real number, so $0 \in \mathbb R$ and $-\infty$ are distinct, and this is a contradiction.